# Percentage Based problems:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A Student gets an aggregate of 60% marks in five subjects in the ratio
>   10:9:8:7:6.If the passing marks are 50% of the maximum marks and each
>   subject has the same maximum marks ,in how many subjects did he pass
>   the examintation

**I have tried:**

```
Consider total mark for each subject as 100
```

1. First subject as 10/40*100 = 25
2. second subject as  9/40*100 = 22.5
3. third subject as  8/40*100 = 20
4. fourth subject as  7/40*100 = 17.5
5. fifth subject as 6/40*100 =  15

Total Marks obtained by five subject is  100

```
As per the given data total aggregate marks is 60% is 100

for 100% is 166.66
```

**After that how to proceed what i am doing mistake please anyone guide me for the answer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you tried, the student had an aggregate score of 20%. Since you want 60%, you would just multiply all of the scores by three, resulting in scores of 75, 67.5, 60, 52.5, and 45.

If 50% is needed to pass an exam, then the student passed 4 out of 5 exams.

Comment: How you are telling i have find out aggregate score of 20%,can you elaborate please,i am not able to understand @browngreen

Comment: Since all 5 exams are worth the same amount of points, the aggregate score is just the average score. So you just add up the scores and divide by 5.

Comment: ok I have understand,Thank you so much  please upvote my question @browngreen